# python on 32 bit

Tags: python, windows-xp

Hi I am running Windows XP, on 32bit. How do I install python? When I run the installation file, it gives me an error saying "installation package not supported by processor type" does python need 64 bit to execute?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally download the 64-bit version? There are two different ones; you want the 32-bit one (the top one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 32-bit options (for Windows) include [ActivePython 2.6.5](http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePython/releases/2.6.5.12/ActivePython-2.6.5.12-win32-x86.msi) and [ActivePython 3.1.2](http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePython/releases/3.1.2.3/ActivePython-3.1.2.3-win32-x86.msi) (ActivePython comes with some extras in addition to the standard python.org release), plain [Python 2.6.5](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.6.5/python-2.6.5.msi) and [3.1.2](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.1.2/python-3.1.2.msi), and commercial solutions such as [Enthought Python](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_sublevels.php) (ActiveState also offers commercial options, but the ones I pointed to are the free "community editions" -- python.org's offerings are also gratis, of course).

Comment: When I install Python on Windows, I always go for ActiveState's distributions, which include pywin32, which allows me to use COM and to access the win32 API.

Comment: @Mike, yep, that's a substantial part of what I meant by "some extras";-).

Comment: @Mike - ActivePython also comes with a *binary* package manager of its own. http://pypm.activestate.com (which makes it easy to install non-trivial packages like MySQLdb or numpy/scipy)

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't require 64-bit. The [download page](http://www.python.org/download/) has both 32-bit and 64-bit downloads.

Comment: Should probably mention that the top one is 32-bit and the X86-64 one is the 64-bit version. Neither one directly says 32-bit or 64-bit.